# MQTT socket webclient connection security concern

Tags: mqtt, password-protection, mosquitto, paho

I used MQTT web client to connect to mosquitto mqtt broker with websocket . I us the the mqttws31.js client js to connect. the connection is Ok without problem.
I use the floowing code

```js
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("iot.eclipse.org", Number(80), "/ws", "clientId");
client.connect({
    onSuccess: onConnect, 
    userName : “Username”,
    password : “password”
});
```

the problem is that this code is inserted in my js file and the user can see the password access to my broker. and if i encrypt the password with md5. the broker will not accept it.
In the case of classic ajax call i can compare the md5 password but with mosquitto i d'ont know if there is a way to do this ???

thanks to help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer without some background into what you want to achieve - What is the application? What are you trying to protect with the MQTT server's username and password?

Using MD5 does not 'encrypt' the password - it just performs a one way conversion to a new string. If someone gets hold of the MD5, then they can still login to your account on the MQTT server.

I suspect the answer is that you should be using the users own credentials to login to the MQTT server - proving it is them. Or even better use a user/session specific token - such as an OAuth token, proving that they are the user but that can be revoked or refreshed if required.

Comment: I use a single account to login to mqtt broker for all my users. I change only the client id to distinguich between them. Haw can users access to my broker with md5. they must decrypt password  to connect to mqtt broker. If I used mqtt js file I must put password in js to connect .

Comment: Perhaps you already solved it, if not: as i understand yoiu want to hide the password from java as this is actually our access to the cloud broker - in such case you build a broker-bridge so each of your users have their own user / password.  as long as they see it and connection is encrypted it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY must use just one password the best you could do is provide the username and password from an AJAX request so it's not stored in the page. These credentials should probably change on a regular basis as well.

This isn't really any protection as anybody will be able to make the same AJAX request to get hold of the credentials but it does mean they are not immediately available in the src.

As @njh said better that each user signs in with their own unique credentials

Comment: even if i let users signs with their own credentials. they can with any mqtt client connect to others users topics and even to brodcast + topics.  for this I would like to not permit them to connect to mosquitto.

Comment: Not if you set the ACL so a given user cna only access the topics they are supposed to see

Comment: Thanks for response i found a mosquitto auth plugin wich do automatic ACL with mysql .  wich do the work i need very well for others facing the same prolem.